# How do I delete all mail coming from a specific domain in a specific user's inbox?

Tags: email

I need help to find the right command to delete all mail in a specific user's inbox coming from specific domains (spam mail from @qq.com or @sohu.com"...)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do :

cd to the user's mailbox

`cd /var/vmail/domain.tld/user/`

Look visually for all the mail coming from qq.com

`grep --color=always "^From:.*qq.com" -r .`

Adjust the grep filter if there are non qq mail included in the results until you only have mail from qq.com, then

`for email in $(grep --color=no "^From:.*qq.com" -l -r .); do echo $email --; rm -rf $email; done;`

This will delete all the e-mails for a specific maildir.

You can of course apply to all mailboxes, but it's dangereous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you help me what command to delete all email of user by year condition. Example: all mail in 2016 year. Sorry if you find troublesome